# MSBuild cannot build a solution when Visual Studio works

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I tried to add CI support in my little github repository, so I configured it to use `appveyor`. But it was unable to build my solution and was failing with odd errors. But it had a build log, so I retyped them in my console and encountered exactly same problem, multiple odd errors like `The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found`

```
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/Pzixel/RemoteClient.git C:\projects\remoteclient
msbuild "C:\projects\remoteclient\RemoteClient\RemoteClient.sln" /verbosity:minimal
```

[image]
And same here in AppVeyor: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Pzixel/remoteclient

However VS2017 is just fine with it:
[image]

Why does it happening and how could it be fixed?

Comment: Make sure you call the correct MSBUILD.

Comment: the version number 15.1.548.43366 is the one that goes with VS2017... is developer command prompt started as the same user?

Comment: @dlatikay I assure you that I didn't install any msbuild manually so this is one which is shipped with VS2017. And of course, `AppVeyor` devops are too good to afford such a lame mistake but they have exactly same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to restore your nuget packages before building your solution. You can download the [nuget.exe here](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html).

Than you can run:

```
nuget restore RemoteClient.sln
msbuild RemoteClient.sln
```

I did a clean checkout and run both commands.